# getting Invalid Number exception : ORA-01722: invalid number while executing query with decimal value in the amount field

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I am getting below invalid Number exception while executing query. please help me on this.
Same query executed properly in DB.

Note: While passing amount with decimal (12.87) I am getting error and With out decimal it works well.

Code:

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

Query = query =em.createNativeQuery(sql, class.forName(search.getDBEntityClassName()));
List result = query.getResultList();

Table Defination:

View:  VW_SEARCH_TMP

AMOUNT : NUMBER (11,2);  // when search with numeric (10) works well. But with decimal (10.12) getting error
ID: NUMBER(11);

Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=VwSearchCheque sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM VW_SEARCH_TMP WHERE ID = ? AND  CHEQUE_NO LIKE ? ESCAPE '' AND  AMOUNT = ? ORDER BY ISSUE_DATE ASC) WHERE ROWNUM<=501 ")

O [EL Warning]: 2020-10-29 16:26:05.799--UnitOfWork(1908522008)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

Error Code: 1722

at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:378)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:469)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:375)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy161.getResultList(Unknown Source)
at ca.on.jus.tms.searchEngine.service.SearchServiceImpl.search(SearchServiceImpl.java:179)
at ca.on.jus.tms.web.controller.search.SearchController.searchEntity(SearchController.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:854)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:765)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException:
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

Answer (score 0):

> While passing amount with decimal (12.87) I am getting error and With out decimal it works well

It looks like decimal point character isn't dot, but comma.

Try `12,87` instead.